# OptionMenu for whole App in Android?

Tags: android, options-menu

I can create an Option Menu for a single Activity. But now I want to create a Logout option in the menu which should be available on all Activities in the App. Is there a possible way to create an Option menu once for an Application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I answered this once on SO, but i forgot where...so here i go again.

Its quite Straightforward.

Create a `BaseActivity` (extends `Activity`). Implement all your Options Menu Code in this. Override your `onOptionsMenu`,etc...

Now, For all your other Activities, instead of extending Activity, extend `BaseActivity`. You'll end up deriving all the options menu code...nifty eh?

Code once, use multiple times...

OOP for the win!

Edit: As WarrenFaith points out, you'll need to create `BaseListActivity` and `BaseMapActivity` if you're using `ListActivity` and `MapActivity`.

Comment: Dont forget to do that for the other types of activity like ListActivity and MapActivity

Comment: Nice Idea. But I want it on `MapActivity` also. My guess: what about the class which extends the Application class. In that class can we create the option Menu?

Comment: I was about to say the same as Praveen... :-)

Comment: @Praveen, i already appended the solution. Check the edit. You cannot override Options menu in the `Application` class, it's not defined there.

Comment: If you have a ListAcivity and regular activity, is there a way to do this WITHOUT have 2 sets of menu code?